# How can I use instr based on code in my SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to Instr one of USER Columns that look like this

Sharyn Rees: sjraos@comcast.net

I want to get the Email from this Column .
Here is the Query i have so far that is pulling back.

```
select mid(User,instr(User,' ')) from mir_goldtest_Rating limit 2;
```

Rees: sjraos@comcast.net

Can anyone help me just pull back the Email Address?

Thanks,
Jamie

```
select mid(User,instr(User,' ')) from mir_goldtest_Rating limit 2;
```

Comment: There is no default order in SQL, using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` to get the "first two records" is pretty much **meaningless**

Answer (score 1):

The `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function might work well here:

```
SELECT
    User,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(User, ' ', -1) AS Email
FROM mir_goldtest_Rating;
```

The above logic would return the last term in the `User` column.

Answer (score 0):

try filter for `:` (:blanck)  instead of blank only

```
select mid(User,instr(User,': ')) from mir_goldtest_Rating limit 2;
```